# Can I assign 0 to a shared_ptr? Why?

Tags: c++, null, c++11

I realized the following compiles fine in GCC 4.7:

```
#include <memory>

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> p;
    p = 0;
}
```

However, there is no assignment operator from `int` or from `int*`, and there is no implicit constructor from either `int` or `int*` either. There is a constructor from `int*`, but that one is explicit. I checked the standard library implementation and the constructor is indeed explicit, and no fishy assignment operators are in sight.

Is the program actually well-formed or is GCC messing with me?

Comment: `0` is the special literal, it converts to `nullptr_t`

Comment: @LucDanton it's because g++ is very smart, and converts `42 - 42` to `0`. Same thing happens (happened?) in Clang, IIRC, it was mentioned at GN2012

Comment: @Abyx You missed the point -- `0` has no special treatment as a literal in the language.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason this works is this short quote from the standard:

`§4.10 [conv.ptr] p1`

> A null pointer constant is an **integral constant expression** (5.19) prvalue of integer type **that evaluates to zero** or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. [...] A null pointer constant of integral type can be converted to a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. [...]

And the fact that `std::shared_ptr` has an implicit constructor from `std::nullptr_t`:

`§20.7.2.2 [util.smartptr.shared] p1`

> `constexpr shared_ptr(nullptr_t) : shared_ptr() { }`

This also allows for oddities like this:

```
#include <memory>

void f(std::shared_ptr<int>){}

int main(){
  f(42 - 42);
}
```

[Live example.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/b30bc04ae80b59ed9639f77cba7fc0aa)

Comment: Regarding oddities like 42 - 42 being null pointer constants, that's likely going away, and [only a literal 0 will be a valid null pointer constant](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#903), in a future version of C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can only assign a shared pointer to another instance of a shared pointer. Assigning the type the shared_pointer holds is not possible. Afaik this is the only overload for the operator:

`shared_ptr& operator=(const shared_ptr& r);`

What you are doing is assigning 0 (which in this case equals NULL) to the pointer, not the value of the type. You type is not even initialized at this point in the code.

Comment: That doesn't really address the question: "why does the compiler accept this without complaint"